# How to prevent exceptions from multiple queries to API in Spring Security OAuth2

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am developing a REST application.
Spring security out of the box oauth2 authorization is used.

But there are problems when the current authorization cookie has expired or deleted and many requests to various api are executed in parallel.
For example:

```
/api/books
/api/categories
/api/authors
```

After these three requests were sent asynchronously, these requests are redirected to authorization.

As a result, I get this picture:

```
/api/books
/api/categories
/api/authors
http://127.0.0.1:8081/login
http://127.0.0.1:8081/login
http://127.0.0.1:8081/login
http://127.0.0.1:8081/oauth/authorize?client_id=client&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8081/login&response_type=code&state=9PO7rO
http://127.0.0.1:8081/oauth/authorize?client_id=client&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8081/login&response_type=code&state=d2O7j1
http://127.0.0.1:8081/oauth/authorize?client_id=client&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8081/login&response_type=code&state=9541sf
http://127.0.0.1:8081/login?code=w7lmSA&state=9PO7rO (one of these queries returns status 401)
http://127.0.0.1:8081/login?code=gf41sd&state=d2O7j1 (one of these queries returns status 401)
http://127.0.0.1:8081/login?code=kj74sx&state=9541sf (one of these queries returns status 401)
```

And it turns out that always one of the last three queries contains an error with status 401 (message: "Authentication Failed: Could not obtain access token")

And I do not understand why this error occurs.

Can you clarify what needs to be done in this situation? Can spring itself solve this problem? It may be necessary to somehow configure additionally.

Answer (score 0):

How I solved this problem:

1. Disable asynchronous processing in the application.properties:

> ```
> security.filter-dispatcher-types=REQUEST, ERROR
> ```

2. Disable sessionFixation in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

   `@Configuration
       public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
           @Override
           public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                   //...
                   http.sessionManagement()
                       .sessionFixation()
                       .none();
           }
       }`